# Remove element of array without splice()

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, array-splice

I'm developing a JavaScript game and I want to keep my memory usage as low as possible.
Therefore I set some objects to null again, so they can get garbage collected.
I read an [article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/05/optimizing-your-javascript-game-for-firefox-os/) which recommends avoiding functions like `Array.splice()`, because this creates a new array, which allocates new memory.

So I've implemented a [JSFiddle](http://jsperf.com/splice-vs-own-function) with an own function, that deletes an element at a specific index and shifts all elements behind, so the length will be set to `length -= 1`. This only affects the existing array instead of creating a new one:

Function to use instead of splice:

```
 deleteElem = function(arr, el) {
      var index = arr.indexOf(el);
      if (index > -1) {
        var len = arr.length - 1;
        for (var i = index; i < len; i++) {
          arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }
        arr.length = len;
      }
    }
```

The JSFiddle for my function is sometimes faster, sometimes slower...
Should I pay more attention to better performance and worse memory, or better memory and worse performance?

What other ways exist to avoid using `Array.splice`?

Comment: If you want to add/remove items often, have you considered using a dictionary instead of an array?

Comment: Well I didn't know that about splice...

Comment: Don't optimise until you know you have a problem. Certainly flat memory usage is a nice ideal, but the design of javascript is so much against it that a gradual sawtooth is almost certain. If the GC that triggers causes an actual, perceivable problem, make tweaks like this (and by that point, you'll have a full program to benchmark so you'll be able to make decisions like this with real data to back it)

Comment: You should have a look at the top two results from the "Related" column on the right.

Comment: Alright, before I make everything worse, I might keep array.splice(). As I also found out, my arrays are not ordered, so I could just move the last element on the current position of the deleted item, instead of shifting all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize how jsperf runs your code. It doesn't run setup for each time it runs your code - the code runs hundreds or thousands of times for each setup.

That means you are using an empty array for 99.999999%  of the calls and thus not measuring anything useful.

You could at least get some sense out of it by measuring it like this http://jsperf.com/splice-vs-own-function/2 however you need to note that the allocation of array of 50 times might blunt the differences and that your method is therefore actually much faster than the benchmark can show.